How to connect to Turso database using Prisma
I'm having trouble connecting my Turso database with Prisma. I'm currently using Prisma version 5.17, and Turso supports Prisma from version 5.4 and up. However, I'm running into issues because Turso provides a URL for database connections, whereas Prisma's documentation seems to expect a file path when using SQLite.
In schema.prisma I have:
datasource db {
  provider = "sqlite"
  url      = "file:./dev.db" // Works locally but not with Turso URL
}

generator client {
  provider      = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["driverAdapters"]
}

//model {...(rest of the code)

I also have these in my auth.js file:
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
import { PrismaLibSQL } from '@prisma/adapter-libsql'
import { createClient } from '@libsql/client'

const libsql = createClient({
  url: `${process.env.TURSO_DATABASE_URL}`,
  authToken: `${process.env.TURSO_AUTH_TOKEN}`,
})

const adapter = new PrismaLibSQL(libsql)
const prisma = new PrismaClient({ adapter })

Error messages:

When using file:./dev.db, Prisma creates the dev.db file but does not connect to Turso.
When using the Turso URL, I encounter build failures.

Question:
How can I configure Prisma to connect to a Turso database when Turso provides a URL and Prisma expects a file path for SQLite? Is there a way to use Turso with Prisma in a manner consistent with Prisma’s expectations, or do I need to use a different approach or library?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

What specific errors are you currently encountering during the build step? It should just work as is when you follow the tutorial as using libsql as an adapter prioritizes the Turso DB URL instead of the specified dev.db file.
